# How to create a deep immutable class in java?

Tags: java, immutability

I want to create a deeply immutable Point with float x and float y, here is my code:

```
public final class Point {
    private final float x;
    private final float y;

    //getter
    public float getX(){return x;}
    public float getY(){return y;}
    
    //constructor
    Point(float x,float y){this.x = x;this.y = y;}
    
    //equals
    public boolean equals(Point p1) {
        if (p1 == this) {return true;}
        Point p = p1;
        return Float.compare(x, p.x) == 0
                && Float.compare(y, p.y) == 0; 
    }
    
    //toString
    public String toString() {
        return "x=" + x + " y=" + y;    
    }
```

However,when I was testing, I found I can assign a new point to a existed point:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Point p1 = new Point(0,0);
    Point p2 = new Point(0,0);
    Point p3 = new Point(0,1);
    p1 = p3; //This operation is working, so it is not immutable.
    System.out.println(p1);
    System.out.println(p1.equals(p2));
}
```

What is wrong I did? How to improve it? Thanks!

Comment: `Point` _is_ deeply immutable.  It's your understanding of Java variables that is the problem: any variable of type `Point` is always a _reference_ to a `Point` object, and can be changed (unless marked `final`).

Comment: If you use `final Point p1 = new Point(0,0);` attempting to re-assign `p1` will result in a compilation error `error: cannot assign a value to final variable p1`.

Comment: `Point` class doesn't have any *depth*, so discussing *deeply* immutable is **pointless** (pun intended).

Answer (score 0):

Your `Point` class is deeply immutable already!

> ```
>  p1 = p3; //This operation is working, so it is not immutable.
> ```

Incorrect. You can still reassign variables of immutable types. That's why they are called *variables*. You can change what they store. You can change `p1` so that it stores a reference to another `Point` object, but what you *can't* do, is to change the properties (e.g. X or Y coordinates) of the `Point` object that `p1` refers to.

To make it so that you can't change a variable's value, you have to make the *variable* `final`:

```
final Point p1 = ...;
```

---

You can write the same code with `String`s, which are known to be immutable. Would you say that `String`s are mutable too? :)

```
String p1 = "a";
String p2 = "b";
String p3 = "c";
p1 = p3; // this operation is working, does this mean that strings are mutable? No!
System.out.println(p1);
System.out.println(p1.equals(p2));
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have designed it, `Point` is already deeply immutable.

When you do the assignment `p1 = p3` you're not mutating the `Point` object itself, you're simply changing which object the variable references.

If you don't want variables to be reassigned, mark them as `final` like this:

```java
final Point p1 = new Point(0,0);
final Point p2 = new Point(0,0);
final Point p3 = new Point(0,1);
p1 = p3; // This won't work now
```

Answer (score 0):

ok first, the constructors in a class java you should create it "public"..if you want to create a **new** instance (object) of this class.

second..java is **a strongly typed lenguage**..then if u created a variable of the same kind. you could replace it (in this example p1 = p3 ) both variables are Point class.

regards!